# CSS font-size is rendered too small, in-between size percentage does not work

Tags: javascript, html, css, fonts, size

Im trying to resize font-size depending on the browser (using Javascript and CSS). Have got the code that will detect browser, and now Firefox is detected. I try to set the font size like so:

```
document.getElementById("parag1").style.fontSize = "80%";
```

but the font size of the paragraph rendered in too small. The browser jumps from normal text size to too small, without a gradual decrease in size. Actually even setting font size with inline CSS `(style="font-size:90%;")` gives me a rendered size too small.

the font size rendering jump is present in both opera and firefox.

This is not what is shown on the font-size page (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-size)

what should I do?

Comment: _Im trying to resize font-size depending on the browser_  -
What do you want to achieve with this?  

_The browser jumps from normal text size to too small, without a gradual decrease in size_ - Do you want animation?

Comment: Have you tried using vh and vw units? https://www.madebymike.com.au/writing/fluid-type-calc-examples/

Comment: resize font-size depending on the browser - this is because firefox renders the text too large compared to chrome / opera. Sometimes the section of text is too large for the container (eg. button or background div).  I don't want animation, just saying, if I type in 90% then 80% it should be a small decrease in size each time not a huge leap.

Comment: Maybe some other style override that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try reducing the font-size with smaller decrements not 10% at a time.

Let's say you start with font-size 40 (px, em, vw anything) and then decrease it to 90%, what is the new font size 40 * 90% = 36,

again when there is more content you reduce it further to 80% so now the actual font-size is 40 * 80% = 32

This is the reason you see big differences in font sizes.

So the solution, 1 - 5% and see what gives you best results.

Answer (score 0):

So I tried making the font-family the same (Arial) and then making both the same font-size(eg 100%). This seems to make both browsers render text same, as they took the same about of space (so I dont need the browser detection for this).

Text sizing seems to be kind of ok now, dont know if its the above fix or I just didn't see the difference earlier (really did seem to be a big jump).